# React Route Issue

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am getting following error.

```
Error: Invariant failed: You should not use <withRouter(Main) /> outside a <Router>.
```

App.js

```
  render() {
    let content;
      content = (
        <div>
          <LeftMenu logout={this.logout} />
          <Main />
        </div>
      )
    return <MuiThemeProvider>{content}</MuiThemeProvider>;
  }
};
```

Main.js

```
    render() {
        return (
            <main>
                <Switch>
                    <Route exact path="/" component={Login} />
                    <Route path="/addFarmer" component={FarmersContainer} />
                </Switch>
            </main>
        );
    }
}
export default withRouter(Main);
```

I have tried using BrowseRoute also but that is also not working.I have wrapped the Main and LeftMenu in Router tag but this is also not working for me.

Comment: You should wrap all your `Route` components in a `BrowserRouter` component

Comment: still getting same issue.

Comment: In which file did you add  `BrowserRouter` component?

Comment: in Main.js file

Comment: I have created a simple demo for using it . Please have a [try](https://codesandbox.io/s/eloquent-einstein-gwbdd?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: You should use the `BrowserRouter` in App.js. `withRouter` works only in child of `BrowserRouter`